# How to avoid hardcoding .html extension across all the links for pages in CQ?

Tags: aem

In our project we have a pathfield in quite a lot of dialog for various custom components which refers/links to pages. After getting the value of this pathfield in the jsp we are adding the html extension manually on it.
e.g.

```
<a href="${properties.tab1_button1_Url}.html" target="_blank" class="btn gb-primary-btn-small aw">${properties.tab1_button1_Title}</a>
```

How to avoid hardcoding **".html"** extension across all the links and get that appended across all the links automatically from CQ ? Do we have a configuration for this ? or Do we need any utility to be created ? Suggestions are welcome. Kindly Note: Solution must work on CQ 5.5.

Comment: why such requirement, you can take author input with html in it. Use regex to validate the input must end with `.html`. As I see in your code block you are just appending `.html` in property value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **pathfield** xtype has a config option called **linkpattern**. This allows you to configure the widget to automatically add an extension *in case the browsefield is used* to select the link. If a user types the text , the extension is not added. Use this option to add '.html' and all internal links will have .html appended (assuming the content authors always use the pathfield's browse option to select the link [which they should be doing ] ). This way the  backend code doesn't have to be responsible for checking if link is external or internal and appending the extension.

`property : "linkPattern" , value : "{0}.html" (String)`

Reference : http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.PathField

Comment: I tried adding it something like this  <button1Url
                                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                            fieldLabel="Button Url"
                                            fieldDescription="Add button url"
                                            name="./tab1_button1_Url"
                                            rootPath="/content/***"
                                            linkPatter="{0}.html"
                                            xtype="pathfield"/> But it didn't worked. Am I missing something Thanks.

Comment: Since this can be achieved in an easier way through dialog config I am accepting this answer. Thanks Sharath. I guess if we want to make sure this applies to each and every links and not just for pathfield (as in my case) the second solution to create Transformer service is more meaningful.

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature is not available anymore in the TouchUI `granite/ui/components/foundation/form/pathbrowser` alternative.

Comment: Can we have similar restriction for TouchUI field, granite/ui/components/foundation/form/pathbrowser

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own [Transformer](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/rewriter/pipeline/Transformer.html) component service, where you can check the attribute href (or you custom attributes) of the anchor tag (a tag). If the link is referecing an relative/internal existing path, than you can alter it by adding .html extension (or for example create absolute link). An example implementation can be found [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-link-rewrite.html).

Comment: upvoted, this should work but I don't see this requirement valid

Comment: Why don't you see this solution as valid? The question was "how to avoid hardcoding the extension in jsps" and not how to make sure that the authors always put valid links. Beside this I don't think that in a pathfield you may require somebody to put relative valid link, because you expect path at the end. Imagine that you want to do something in the backend with this path (for example checking for resource existence), than you have to remove the extension.

Comment: I am saying solution you mentioned should work, read it carefully please.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. You are talking about the requirement in the question...